# How to publish multiple IP addresses belonging to different interfaces of the same device through Avahi Daemon?

Tags: raspberry-pi, webserver, avahi

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. I'm using it as a local Web Server. I want to publish the IP address of the Server on the local network for which I've used Avahi Daemon. My Pi has two interfaces, `eth0` and `wlan0`. `eth0` is connected to a router and `wlan0` is used as a hotspot for other wireless devices to connect and access the website. Both interfaces have different IP addresses. What I want is that if another device is connecting to the Pi Server using `eth0` then I want to publish the IP address belonging to `eth0` and if some device connects to the server using `wlan0` then I want to publish the IP address belonging to `wlan0` which is not happening right now. The Pi server is not resolving on both `eth0` and `wlan0`. Any solution?